# Two-dimensional arrays + Destructuring = Type error

Tags: typescript

Could someone please explain to me TypeScript behavior here?

- **JavaScript**

  ```js
  const test1 = [
      ['a', 'b'],
      ['c', 'd'],
  ];

  const test2 = [
      ...[
          ['a', 'b'],
          ['c', 'd'],
      ],
  ];

  console.log(JSON.stringify(test1) === JSON.stringify(test2));
  ```

  Logs `true` as expected (arrays are identical).
- **TypeScript**

  ```js
  const test1: [string, string][] = [
      ['a', 'b'],
      ['c', 'd'],
  ];

  const test2: [string, string][] = [
      ...[
          ['a', 'b'],
          ['c', 'd'],
      ],
  ];
  ```

  This, however, leads to the following error on `test2`:

  ```
  Type 'string[][]' is not assignable to type '[string, string][]'.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, string]'.
      Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
  ```

Here is a [reproducer on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CMAuGBtaAnAlmA5gDQzZ74C665MAvBgFAxMYDkAhi8SwEYvmGNm6FsE4wWAEz4DyAbnr1QkWAmgAmNJii4CxUgUrU66QUwB0Fk82usOXXv1M3horlMfXHchUoggANvBm-iD4ABQAUgDKAPIAcmb6+DgAZgCeYapQSACUtDR00fGJ2mSpGVlqeQD84gCCWFhsaRAwbFjwMDgS8GBQOMBs-iwwaCx1AEoTdQCaUTCTAKIwACIAkgBiG4sTi3EAKgCELDnyQA).

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there any way to get this to work without resorting to some ugly type casting?

---

### UPDATE

Here is a more concrete example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
const someValues = [1, 2, 3];

const test3: [string, string][] = [
    ...someValues.map(value => ['some string', 'another string']),
];
```

---

### UPDATE #2

Following Алексей Мартинкевич advice, I can confirm that this works:

```js
const someValues = [1, 2, 3];

const test3: (readonly [string, string])[] = [
    ...someValues.map(i => ['a', 'a'] as const),
];
```

Would there be a more readable/less complex solution though?
*(thinking of my coworkers and 2-weeks-future-me wondering what I did there :D)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific concrete case, you can indicate the return type on the arrow function given to `map`:

```js
const someValues = [1, 2, 3];

const test3: [string, string][] = [
    ...someValues.map((value): [string, string] => ['some string', 'another string']),
];
```

You could also remove the type on the variable if you think it's explicit enough:

```js
const test4 = [
    ...someValues.map((value): [string, string] => ['some string', 'another string']),
];
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, working and easy to read & understand. I feel sorry that I cannot accept both answers though, since Алексей Мартинкевич was technically right with the information I provided at first. Thanks a lot to both of you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This construction has type `string[][]`, so it cannot be assigned to `[string, string][]`.

```js
...[
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['c', 'd'],
]
```

The following should work:

```js
const test1: [string, string][] = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd'],
];

const test2: [string, string][] = [
    ...test1,
];
```

You can use `as const`, but you need to keep everything readonly:

```js
const test2: (readonly [string, string])[] = [
    ...[
        ['a', 'b'],
        ['c', 'd'],
    ] as const
]
```

Typescript assumes that array can be changed, so it uses more wide type by default.

Comment: I'm aware that [...test1] would work, I probably over-simplified the issue too much ;)
I updated the question with a more realistic scenario (the one that's bothering me).

Comment: Your last suggestion is indeed working, but makes things less readable imo (maybe I'm just not experimented enough with TypeScript though). I'll accept your answer if no one comes with an easier solution. Thanks a lot!